# Bootstrap nav link is not opening

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Link inside Bootstrap nav-menu is not opening. When you click on it nothing opens.

[image: Using bootstrap]

Cart file does not open when I click on the Cart hyper link. I double checked the path and it is correct.

Master file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
            <li>
                <a href="Cart/Cart.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><asp:Label ID="CartCountL" runat="server" CssClass="badge badge-warning" text="2"/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/UI/Home.aspx">
              <img id="MMLogo" src="/Images/Logo/MM.jpg" alt="MurkyMuse Logo" Title="MurkyMuse Logo" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/UI/Home.aspx">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">DAILY LIFE
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/UI/ComingSoon.aspx">Art</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/UI/ComingSoon.aspx">Outfits</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="/UI/Shop/Shop.aspx">SHOP</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/UI/About.aspx">ABOUT<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/UI/About/OurStory.aspx">OUR STORY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/UI/ComingSoon.aspx">MEDIA</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/UI/Contact.aspx">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Cart* menu item does not behave like a standard link, because you have `data-toggle="dropdown"` defined on it. As part of the dropdown functionality, Bootstrap click listeners use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the click event triggered on these elements, thus blocking the native link behavior.

In case the *Cart* item does not have a dropdown, but it should behave as a standard link, remove the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute and the `.dropdown-toggle` class from that, and it should work.